# Use of Replace function

Tags: replacement

I would like to replace in an expression two functions `x[t]` and `D[x[t],t]` by two variables `x` and `xd`.

I use the `Replace` function like this :

```
Tsys0 = 1/2 Subscript[m, 3] Derivative[1][x][t]^2 + 
  IG1 (Derivative[1][x][t]/
     (r - ((-l^2 + r^2 + x[t]^2) Derivative[1][x][t])/
       (2 r x[t]^2))^2)/(2 (1 - (-l^2 + r^2 + x[t]^2)^2/(4 r^2 x[t]^2)))

Subscript[T, sysmod] = 
 Replace[Subscript[T, sys0], {D[x[t], t] -> xd }, {x[t] -> x}]
```

But the function doesn't work.

I probably don't use well the function.

May you help me to use correctly the Replace function for that purpose?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: The error message occurs because you have too many arguments.  More importantly, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

```
Tsys0 = 1/2 Subscript[m, 
    3] Derivative[1][x][
     t]^2 + (IG1 (Derivative[1][x][t]/
         r - ((-l^2 + r^2 + x[t]^2) Derivative[1][x][
            t])/(2 r x[t]^2))^2)/(2 (1 - (-l^2 + r^2 + 
           x[t]^2)^2/(4 r^2 x[t]^2)));
Subscript[T, sysmod] = Tsys0 /. {D[x[t], t] -> xd, x[t] -> x}
```

[image]

Comment: @m_goldberg, very odd. In my Version 10.0.2 Im getting the same result as you.

Comment: I just evaluated your code in a fresh _Mathematica_ session. I got your answer this time. Don't know what went wrong in my old session where I first evaluated it and got a different answer. Sorry I complained. Will delete my comment.